# gotoAndStop makes it go to the next frame in Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem: I have a movieclip ("gesprekkencivcen") with several frames and layers. I've put this action on a certain button at frame 1:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, conv1);
function conv1(evt:MouseEvent):void{ 
    MovieClip(root).gesprekkencivcen.gotoAndStop(23);
}
```

Now, in stead of going to frame 23 when I click the button it goes to the next frame (which is frame 2). What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Perhaps there is another listener that probably listens for `MouseEvent.CLICK` and too alters that clip's playhead position. Also check if that function is actually called.

Comment: YES! That's it! I have another button (in the root) with this code:
`this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startconv1);
    function startconv1(evt:MouseEvent):void{ 
  gesprekkencivcen.gotoAndStop(2);
 }` When I delete the action on that one the problem is solved. However. I'd really like the action to work on that one was well...

Comment: It seems I cannot add more than one MouseEvent_CLICK without ruining the others. How to solve this?

Comment: Most likely you were putting these both listeners to the same object that's the parent of both buttons. Do like this: `button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, startconv1); button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, conv1);` and change `button1` and `button2` to the respective buttons' names.